# loop: while and switch basic calculator java

Tags: java

Im a begginer ^_^ im trying to make a calculator as my first java program.. this calculator loops through out the process until you choose quit, my problem is even i choose quit it still asked for num1 and num2 i want it to exit right away.

```
import java.io.Console;
public class Calc {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Console console = System.console();
        loop: while(true) {
        String operator = console.readLine("Enter Operation or Quit: ");
        String num1 = console.readLine("Enter num1: ");
        String num2 = console.readLine("Enter num2: ");
        int x = Integer.parseInt(num1);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(num2);
        int sum = add(x,y);
        int sub = minus(x,y);
        int mul = product(x,y);
        int div = divide(x,y);

        switch(operator) {
            case "addition":
            System.out.println(sum);
            break;
            case "subtraction":
            System.out.println(sub);
            break;
            case "multiplication":
            System.out.println(mul);
            break;
            case "division":
            System.out.println(div);
            break;
            case "quit":
            System.exit(0);
            break loop;
            default:
            System.out.println("Out of topic");
            }
        }

        }
    public static int add(int x, int y) {
        return x+y;
    }
    public static int minus(int x, int y) {
        return x-y;
    }
    public static int product(int x, int y) {
        return x*y;
    }
    public static int divide (int x, int y) {
        return x/y;
    }

}
```

Comment: Downvoting because I want to see what you've *tried* to do to solve the problem, or what you think might be causing the problem. Otherwise it looks like you gave up at the first moment of things not working and went straight here for help. This isn't a programming question, it's a logic flow question, you have to think about what needs to happen first, second, third.

Answer (score 2):

> even i choose quit it still asked for num1 and num2 i want it to exit right away

In that case check whether the option is to quit before asking for the next two values.

```
String operator = console.readLine("Enter Operation or Quit: ");
if ("quit".equals(operator))
   return;
String num1 = console.readLine("Enter num1: ");
```

BTW, there is no much point having a method which is longer and more complex than the expression it wraps, unless the expression is obscure.  You can assume that the meaning of `+` is not obscure.

Comment: ty sir Peter ^_^ now im very enlighten

Comment: sir another thing what if i inputted values out of choices or other way i mis spelled it how i can directly display my default (Out of Topic) without num1 num2 showing first? tnx